# Expand the width of div

Tags: html, css

I am working on one section in which I am using two div's with float left.
I want to expand the width of left div when right div is not visible.

This is what i am doing:

```
<style>

    body{
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        font-size:12px
    }
    .mainContainer{
        width:300px; 
        border:blue solid 1px; 
        overflow:hidden
    }
    .leftCont{
        float:left; 
        border:green solid 1px
    }
    .rightCont{
        float:left; 
        border:red solid 1px
    }

</style>

<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="leftCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    </div>
    <div class="rightCont">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to fix this with div/css only.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Rohit Mehra You want to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/creTj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind, you could achieve that by changing your markup a bit by putting your right `div` before the left one:

```
<div class="rightCont"></div>
<div class="leftCont"></div>
```

And then, floating your `div.rightCont` to the right and then give the left one an overflow whitout floating it:

```
.leftCont{
  overflow: hidden;
  border: green solid 1px
}
.rightCont{
  float: right;
  border: red solid 1px
}
```

Comment: @ pzin This is the nice trick to fix this. I will apply this code.Hope it works.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With `float:left` it won't be possible, try using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

```
body{
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        font-size:12px
    }
    .mainContainer{
        width:300px; 
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px solid blue;
        display:table;
    }
    .leftCont{        
        border:green solid 1px;
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .rightCont{
        border:red solid 1px;
        display:table-cell;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/uVykV/1/)**

Comment: This is nice but it doesnt work in ie7. Any solution for that w/ using JQUERY. Thanks